# Android: MVP how does the model communicate back with the presenter?

Tags: android, design-patterns, mvp

My question is: When I'm doing some business in the model, How can send data back to the presenter depending on a callback method such as onSuccess?

I'm simply try to implement a Facebook login while using the MVP design pattern.
First I was confused as how to register the callback manager outside of the view as I need the context.
I decided to inject the context in the model, which is not a good practice as I under stood, the model should not have any android components.

Comment: Depends on many aspects of your architecture. For example you can make the login blocking in the presenter even if it is asynchronous on the data manager.

Comment: I read I could use an eventbus between the presenter and the model.. How do I normally decide which approach to take and unify it through my project.. Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can use EventBus.

https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus

In your code don't forget registering and unregistering from EventBus.

Comment: That's what I'm trying at the moment. Thanks for replying.